# What is it called when you intentionally expose a film negative during development?

Tags: terminology, film, effect, negative, processing

Back in the film days, there was  technique of exposing a negative, while it was being developed, which distorted the image, sometime very strikingly.
This manipulation had a name, which I cannot remember.

Answer (score 8):

You're be looking for the [Sabatier Effect](http://www.ilfordphoto.com/applications/page.asp?n=154).

> Sabatier discovered that when a plate was exposed, developed, and washed but not fixed, it could be given a second exposure to light which would partially reverse the image when development was continued.

The technique can be used on film or when printing but is more commonly used when printing as the effects can be better controlled in the darkroom.

It is frequently confused with Solarization which occurs from a gross overexposure.  The effects can look similar.

Comment: Frequently confused with, yes, but it's very likely that you'll find the term "solarization" used more frequently when digging into the old popular literature, so it's worth trying both if you're spelunking in the archives.